# How do I minimize to tray when I close a Chrome app?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, background-process

I would like to minimize my app to the tray when the user presses close, similar to how Spotify operates. It doesn't have to a Windows system tray, but I do want my window to be closed.

However, the scripts in the webpage should be running so that a close behaves similarly to a minimize without a window.

Is there a way to do this besides keeping scripts in the `manifest.json`?

Answer (score 2):

No way to do this.

The Close icon is system level. Codes in Chrome app can not work with it.

Comment: how does hangouts do it?

Comment: @MozenRath The ability to have a tray icon is a private API.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the native window controls using

`chrome.app.window.create("any.html", { frame: "none" })`

You can hide a window using

```
chrome.app.window.current().hide()
```

And show it using

```
chrome.app.window.current().show()
```

App Window Docs: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window